# How to calculate $\int_2^4 \frac{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)}}{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)} + \sqrt{\ln(3+x)}} \space dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

How to calculate $$\int_2^4 \frac{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)}}{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)} + \sqrt{\ln(3+x)}} \space\mathrm{d}x$$

Answer (score 2):

> Short answer: $I=1$.

**Proof:** 
Note that 
\begin{align*}
I := \int_2^4 \frac{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)}}{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)} + \sqrt{\ln(3+x)}} \space dx\\
\overset{\text{substitute } v := 3-x}{=} - \int_{-1}^1 -\frac{\sqrt{\ln(6+v)}} {\sqrt{\ln(6+v)} + \sqrt{\ln(6-v)}} \space dx\\
\overset{\text{substitute } u := -v}{=} \int_{-1}^1 -\frac{\sqrt{\ln(6-u)}}{\sqrt{\ln(6+u)} + \sqrt{\ln(6-u)}} \space dx
\end{align*}

Thus, $2\cdot I = \displaystyle\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\sqrt{\ln(6-x)}+\sqrt{\ln(6+x)}}{\sqrt{\ln(6+x)} + \sqrt{\ln(6-x)}} \space dx = \int_{-1}^1 1 = 2$, i.e. $I = 1$

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathbf I =\int_2^4 \frac{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)}}{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)} + \sqrt{\ln(3+x)}}\mathrm{dx}=\int_2^4 \frac{\sqrt{\ln(9-(4+2-x))}}{\sqrt{\ln(9-(4+2-x))} + \sqrt{\ln(3+(4+2-x))}}\mathrm{dx} \qquad\text{(Why?)}$$
So
$\mathbf I =\displaystyle\int_2^4 \frac{\sqrt{\ln(3+x)}}{\sqrt{\ln(3+x)} + \sqrt{\ln(9-x)}}\mathrm{dx}$.

Then $2\mathbf I =\int_2^4 \mathrm{dx}=2$.